# FileProvider Xamarin not displaying file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-fileprovider

I’m trying to display a PDF file using a file provider. However when the PDF reader opens it does not contain the content of the file. The file is stored in the internal storage of the application within the files folder.

Manifest:

```
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.mycom.myapp.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

File_paths:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="export" />
</paths>
```

pdfViewRenderer.cs:

```
string libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);   
var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, fileName);


string application = "application/pdf";
Java.IO.File javaFile = new Java.IO.File(fileName);//externalPath  


Android.Net.Uri androidURI = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Forms.Context.ApplicationContext, "com.mycom.myapp.fileprovider", javaFile);


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(androidURI, Filetype); 
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);


Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Open PDF"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not *directly* access a file within the application's `.apk`, the `.apk' does not present itself as a filesystem.

You can copy an `AndroidAsset` to your application cache directory and then grant `FileProvider` permission to a file-based `Uri` to allowed external applications to access that file within your app's sandbox.

Add a `provider` within your `AndroidManifest`'s **`application`** element:

```
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="com.sushihangover.artificialgravitycalc"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/cache_path" />
```

Then add an xml file whose filename matches the provider's `android:resource:` to your `Resources/xml` that contains the path that you are granting access to:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="appcache" path="." />
</paths>
```

Note: You might have to add the `xml` directory to your `Resources` folder as by default it is not added via the basic `Xamarin.Android` project template. (and it must be named `xml`, lowercase)

Add your `.pdf` to the `Assets` directory and make sure that it is flagged as a `AndroidAsset` build type:

[image]

Now you can copy that `Asset` to your app's cache directory, create a `FileProvider`-based `Uri`, grant read access to it, and try to open it. In this case you need at least one installed application that publishes that it handles the `application/pdf` mime-type:

```
var pdfAssetName = "PlayScriptLanguageSpecification.pdf";
var savePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (var assetStream = Application.Context.Assets.Open(pdfAssetName))
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int readCount = 0;
    do
    {
        readCount = assetStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    } while (readCount > 0);
}
var targetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
var file = new Java.IO.File(savePath);
var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, PackageName, file);
targetIntent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
targetIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
targetIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
Intent intent = Intent.CreateChooser(targetIntent, "Open File");
StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This looks good, however the result produces a .tmp will this open within a PDF viewer?

Comment: @Simon Works fine for all the PDF viewers that Ive used, but you could use `GetTempPath` and add a filename of your choosing.. i..e.`var savePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), pdfAssetName);`

Comment: I just worked with it yesterday... And your solution is good however still gave me the same problem. Looking further I found that there was an issue in permissions. The receiving app was getting a Permission Denial. By granting the URI Permission this resolved it and I could use my original code.. Am I wrong to use the internal storage if it works?

Comment: Additionally I assumed the ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission flag should have prevented this right?